# GTM push is including previous checkout inside the purchase

Tags: google-tag-manager

google tag manager - i am calling a checkout and then a purchase consecutively... It seems the "checkout" portion is included in the final "purchase".

see the results from this below.......... i get the first checkout event fine. the second event for purchase contains the first checkout json?

```
try {
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'ecommerce_checkout',
    'eventCategory': 'Ecommerce',
    'eventAction': 'Checkout',
    'ecommerce': {
        'checkout': {
            'actionField': {
                'step': 5,
                'option': 'checkoutstep5'
            },
            'products': [{
                'name': 'test',
                'id': 10101,
                'category': 'Testing',
            }]
        }
    }
}); } catch (egtm) {}


try {
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'ecommerce_purchase',
    'eventCategory': 'Ecommerce',
    'eventAction': 'Purchase',
    'ecommerce': {
        'purchase': {
            'actionField': {
                'id': 111,
                'revenue': 10
            },
            'products': [{
                'name': 'test',
                'id': 10101,
                'price': 10,
                'category': 'test',
                'variant': 'test',
                'quantity': 1
            }]
        }
    }
}); } catch (egtm) {}
```

Resulting GTM :

```
{
gtm: {start: 11111111111, uniqueEventId: 429},
event: 'ecommerce_purchase',
eventCategory: 'Ecommerce',
eventAction: 'Purchase',
ecommerce: {
    checkout: {
    actionField: {step: 5, option: 'checkoutstep5'},
    products: [
    {
        name: 'test',
        id: 10101,
        category: 'Testing',
        price: '10',
        variant: '',
        quantity: 1
    }
    ]
    },
    purchase: {
    actionField: {id: '145245', revenue: '10.00'},
    products: [
    {
        name: 'test',
        id: 10101,
        category: 'Testing',
        price: '10',
        variant: '',
        quantity: 1
    }
    ]
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean the dataLayer before you get to the Purchase by doing another dataLayer.push with the ecommerce : undefined .

On the other side, you want dataLayer to have the information about the transaction on the Checkout completed, so that you can send it to GA or some other tracking engine, right? In that case, you need only to get the values from ecommerce.purchase variable, and you don't need to worry about ecommerce.checkout still being there as it is not messing up anything for you anyway.